# What formats does the MediaElement support?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

In C# what formats does the `MediaElement` support?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Below is a rollup list of formats codecs supported by the `MediaElement`. These encodings are supported regardless of the file name extension.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(v=vs.95).aspx

- Video

  - Raw Video
  - RGBA format

    - Uncompressed 32 bit Alpha Red, Green, Blue.
    - On Windows Phone 7, the alpha channel is ignored.
  - YV12 format- YCrCb(4:2:0)

    - Uncompressed YCrCb(4:2:0).
    - Not supported on Windows Phone 7.
  - RGBA - 32 bit Alpha Red, Green, Blue
  - Windows Media Video and VC-1 formatsWMV1: Windows Media Video 7

    - Supports Simple, Main, and Advanced Profiles.
    - Supports only progressive (non-interlaced) content.
  - WMV2: Windows Media Video 8
  - WMV3: Windows Media Video 9

    - Supports Simple and Main Profiles.
    - Supports only progressive (non-interlaced) content.
  - WMVA: Windows Media Video Advanced Profile, non-VC-1
  - WVC1: Windows Media Video Advanced Profile, VC-1

    - Supports Advanced Profile.
    - Supports only progressive (non-interlaced) content.
  - H264 (ITU-T H.264 / ISO MPEG-4 AVC) formats

    - Supports H.264 and MP43 codecs.
    - Supports Base, Main, and High Profiles.
    - Windows Phone 7 supports up to Level 3.0.
    - Note that level 3.0 defines the maximum supported resolution for 30fps as 720x480. Other frame rates have different maximum supported resolutions.
    - Supports only progressive (non-interlaced) content.
    - Supports only 4:2:0 chroma subsampling profiles.
    - Desktop Silverlight only supports the Annex B NAL format (i.e. start codes).
    - Note, that media libraries, such as the SmoothStreamingMediaElement, support the AVC NAL format by programmatically converting AVC NALs to Annex B NALs. As Silverlight supports partial encryption of H.264 samples, this conversion can occur on encrypted content as well if the NAL headers are not encrypted. The Annex B NAL format is described in MPEG-4 Part 10.
    - Supports PlayReady DRM with Mp4 (H264 and AAC-LC)
  - H.263 format

    - Not supported by desktop versions of Silverlight.
    - Not supported by the MediaStreamSource class in Windows Phone 7.
  - MPEG-4 Part 2 format

    - Supports Simple and Advanced Profiles.
- Audio

  - PCM / WAV format"1". This is Linear 8 or 16 bit Pulse Code Modulation. Roughly speaking, this is WAV format.

    - This is Linear 8 or 16 bit Pulse Code Modulation. Roughly speaking, this is WAV format.
  - Microsoft Windows Media Audio Standard formats."353" - Microsoft Windows Media Audio v7, v8 and v9.x Standard (WMA Standard)
  - Microsoft Windows Media Audio Professional formats."354" - Microsoft Windows Media Audio v9.x and v10 Professional (WMA Professional)

    - Supports full fidelity decoding of WMA 10 Professional Low Bit Rate (LBR) modes in the 32-96 kbps range.
    - Multichannel (5.1 and 7.1 surround) audio content is automatically mixed down to stereo.
    - 24 bit audio will return silence.
    - Sampling Rates beyond 48000 return an invalid format error code in same-domain and a 4001 in cross-domain scenarios.
  - MP3 "85" -– (ISO MPEG-1 Layer III) format (MP3).
  - AAC"255" - (ISO Advanced Audio Coding) (AAC)format.

    - Supports Low Complexity (AAC-LC) decoding at full fidelity (up to 48 kHz).
    - High Efficiency (HE-AAC) encoded content. will decode only at half fidelity (up to 24 kHz).

      1. HE-AAC v1 (AAC+) and HE-AAC v2 (eAAC+) supported.
      2. Desktop Silverlight will decode only at half fidelity (up to 24 kHz).
    - Multichannel (5.1 surround) audio content is not supported.
  - AMR-NB (Adaptive Multi-Rate Narrow Band) format

    - Not supported by desktop versions of Silverlight.
    - Not supported by the MediaStreamSource class.
- Additional Restrictions

  - The following codec formats are not supported on any Silverlight platform:

    - Windows Media Screen
    - Windows Media Audio Professional Lossless
    - Windows Media Voice
  - Windows Phone 7 does not support dynamic changes in video frame size

Comment: Thanks! If I was to create an animation for my app, which format would be best?

Comment: Ask another question. Comments are only for clarifing and are not for answers neither for questions :)