# WPF Media Element can't play *.wmv or *.avi files

Tags: c#, wpf

It works fine with *.mp4 files, but i can't run any *.wmv or *.avi file.

This is what my XAML looks like:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Margin="0" Source="C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Natur.wmv" Volume="1"/>
```

What i tried is:

- trying different *.wmv or *.avi videos, but i can't play any of them.
- *.mp4 work fine.

I have Windows Media Player version 12 (cause 10+ is recommended for using MediaElement) and i can play all those videos without any problems in Windows Media Player.

Comment: MediaElement doesn't have support for the wide range for formats. you can use any vlc plugin for .net. they are also available for WPF specifically. you will need to have vlc player installed on your machine. (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet)

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan i will give that a try, thanks. What formats are supported in MediaElement? Is it only *.mp4?

Comment: Google is your friend btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394220/what-formats-does-the-mediaelement-support

Comment: as long as they collect my data unsolicited, DuckDuckGo is more my friend ;)